# Calculating NPV in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am confused as how to create interest rate input as an argument
When I try to list Dim Rate as single an error box says duplicate argument
The purpose of this function is to calculate NPV for a set of cash flows (myarray)

```
Public Function myNPV(rate As Single, r As Range) As Single
    Dim myArray(64) As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim sum As Double

    For i = 0 To n
    Next i

    For Each elem In r
        myArray(i) = elem.Value
        myArray(i) = myArray(i) / ((1 + rate / 100) ^ i)
        i = i + 1
    Next elem
End Function
```

Comment: Did you leave out the code that generates the error? Is there a line not shown that says `Dim rate as Single` in your function body? Also are you aware there are already present value (`PV`) and net present value (`NPV`) function in excel?

Comment: You are getting an error because you are declaring `rate` as an argument in the function. Don't recreate the wheel here. Use the formulas that @Brad has already mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

**n** is zero.  The **For** loop does nothing.

**myNPV** never gets assigned a value in the UDF